# How to create a search widget module for CodeIgniter using HMVC Modular Extensions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, widget, hmvc

Can someone give me a best approach in using HMVC Modular Extension in CodeIgniter. I like my modules to be stand alone like a plugin. so my modules have its own controller,model,view and libraries,config etc.. So when I want to reuse the module in other projects I can just copy the and paste the module in other projects. But something is not clear for me, for example I made a search module that displays a search form and processes the searching of posts. I call it in the view of the site using echo modules::run('search/search/search_form'); and when I submit the form I wanted to output the result in the current page so I store the search_results in a session variable to let the current page access the search results, but I think its not a good idea because sessions has a 4kb limit if I'm not mistaken. How can I output the search results in the current page by not using session variable? Like I want to use the $this->load->view() function and pass the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would only put the search string and the current page in the session and make a listener in MY_Controller which checks for a search string in the session. If session contains a search string run the search method from your search controller / module and pass that data to your current page (e.g. module).